# My mongodb total document size is over 16mb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I just noticed that my mongodb total document size is over 16mb, I know the total document size limit is 16mb. What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you have single documents with a size larger than 16mb? The size limit of 16mb only applies to **single documents**. The **total** size of all documents in a collection is unlimited.

Answer (score 1):

In you image, `Total Document Size` tells you the size of all documents in a given collection. As @Tobias said, limit of 16mb only applies to a single document in a collection. So as long as some document itself does not exceed the 16mb of size, you are good to go.

However, the maximum document size of 16mb applies for `BSON-document`, and if you want to have documents with more then 16mb of size, you should use [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/):

> GridFS is a specification for storing and retrieving files that exceed
> the BSON-document size limit of 16 MB.